# R: How to add geom_line to connect geom_point - points of an existing ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Lets take the following data.frame as an example:

```
data <- data.frame(windowSize1=rep(c("1 week","2 weeks"),each=6),
                   windowSize2 = rep(c("0 weeks","1 week"),6),
                   Modell = rep(c("SVM","random Forest","NN"), 4),
                   MSE=c(rnorm(12))
                   )

ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=data, aes(x=windowSize1, y=MSE, color=Modell, shape=windowSize2),size=2)
```

I want to add to this plot a line connecting  the MSE value of row 1 in the data and of row 7 in the same color of the reelated SVM - datapoints.
But when I try:

```
  ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=data, aes(x=windowSize1, y=MSE, color=Modell, shape=windowSize2),size=2)+
  geom_line(data=data[c(1,7),],aes(x=windowSize1, y=MSE, color=Modell) )
```

I get the error method: "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

Does anyone understand this message? (I don't understand it, because both rows of the data.frame are from the Group "SVM")

Comment: you should move the `data` statement and the `aes` statement into the `ggplot` function. Try that

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `windowSize1` is a factor, and therefore `ggplot` does not know how to draw a line between the values. If you change `windowSize1` to integer, then it works:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(windowSize1=rep(c(1,2),each=6),
                   windowSize2 = rep(c("0 weeks","1 week"),6),
                   Modell = rep(c("SVM","random Forest","NN"), 4),
                   MSE=c(rnorm(12))
)

ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=data, aes(x=windowSize1, y=MSE, color=Modell, shape=windowSize2),size=2)+
geom_line(data=data[c(1,7),],aes(x=windowSize1, y=MSE, color=Modell) )
```

[image]

EDIT:
But there is actually a better solution that leaves the factors as they are. The trick is to make ggplot understand between which points it is supposed to draw lines. You can do this with the `group` argument. In this case the `Modells` build the groups, so:

```
data <- data.frame(windowSize1=rep(c("0 weeks","1 week"),each=6),
                   windowSize2 = rep(c("0 weeks","1 week"),6),
                   Modell = rep(c("SVM","random Forest","NN"), 4),
                   MSE=c(rnorm(12)))
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=data, aes(x=windowSize1, y=MSE, color=Modell, shape=windowSize2,size=2))+
  geom_line(data=data[c(1,7),],aes(x=windowSize1, y=MSE, color=Modell, group=Modell,size=1) )
```

[image]